# ###error### in TortoiseSVN - what does it mean?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We are using TortoiseSVN as our Subversion client and today we have started seeing some strange errors being reported in one of our repositories. When using the Repository Browser, one of the branches has `###error###` listed in the Author column and `(no date)` listed in the Date column.

We are unable to perform any kind of operation on this part of the repository e.g. checkout, log, commit etc.; attempting to do so results in the following error being reported:

```
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to
     REPORT request for '/svn/vtx/!svn/vcc/default'.
```

On the face of it we seem to have some kind of corruption with one or more files. I have identified the last revision at which I *can* checkout the failing branch but anything beyond this point results in the errors described above.

If the branch in question *has* become corrupt, is there any way to recover it to a known good state or will we have to perform a full-scale restoration using our most recent backup?

We have tried running `svnadmin verify` on the server but this did not report any problems.

If it makes any difference we are using TortoiseSVN 1.6.12.20536 on Windows 7 64-bit. Our Subversion server is 1.6.4.

Comment: Good thing you have backups to restore from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw some similar problems a few days ago - though I was using git-svn to pull down a copy of the entire repository at the time.

Doing it from a machine with a faster connection to the outside world, and therefore the repository as well, succeeded without further issue. I think it just got a bit stuck, and failed rather than keep retrying.

Seeing that `svnadmin verify` reports OK, I'd be inclined to believe that, and not think there was a problem with the repo itself, just the connection to it.

Comment: We're still not quite sure what caused the problems we encountered but we managed to restore from a backup without any data loss. I think you're on the right track with your comment about connection speed because the developer whose commit failed works remotely and sometimes suffers from a slow connection.